# Delete all lines except the ones that have certain words with TextWrangler

Tags: command-line, xml, textwrangler

I have many files  which I want to delete all the lines except the lines that have certain words.
I tried to do it with TextWrangler: Text > Process Lines Containing…
But only does it word by word.
I am on OS X.
I would appreciate your help. Thank you

My files are like these: (other files have more lines)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<movie>
    <title>Robotron</title>
    <originaltitle></originaltitle>
    <id></id>
    <mpaa></mpaa>
    <actor>
      <name></name>
      <thumb>   .jpg</thumb>
      <name></name>
      <thumb>   .jpg</thumb>
    </actor>
  <genre>Action</genre>
  <genre>Drama</genre>
</movie>
```

I want to delete all the lines except the lines that have the words: xml, movie, title, id, actor, name and genre; and copy them to a new file. Is this possible?

Desired result in new file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<movie>
    <title>Robotron</title>
    <id>Robotron</id>
  <actor>
    <name></name>
    <name></name>
  </actor>
  <genre>Action</genre>
  <genre>Drama</genre>
</movie>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Works with:

```
(<\?xml|<movie>|</movie>|</id>|</title>|<actor>|</actor>|</name>|</genre>|</year>)
```

thank you, anyway.